# Connect to swipe signal in GNOME St

Tags: gnome, clutter, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

Trying to connect a `StButton` to a `swipe` signal, I get an error:

```
JS ERROR: Extension screensaver-dashboard@singularities.org: Error: No signal 'swipe' on object 'StButton
```

However, I can see the signal among Clutter Actions https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterSwipeAction.html#ClutterSwipeAction.signals

Maybe it is not supported yet? O should I use another kind of `StWidget` to connecting to `swipe` signal?

Answer (score 1):

[`StWidget`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10~1.0_api/st.widget) is a [`ClutterActor`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter5~5_api/clutter.actor) which has no `swipe` signal.

The signal you want to connect to is on a [`ClutterSwipeAction`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter5~5_api/clutter.swipeaction) so you probably want to create a new one, connect to the swipe signal on that object, then [add the action to the actor](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter5~5_api/clutter.actor#method-add_action).

Comment: I just tested it, the code worked, but it didn't show anything. I tested it both with a `St.Label` and a `St.Button`

`
    const swipeAction = new Clutter.SwipeAction()
    swipeAction.connect('swipe', this._onTemperatureSetpointChange.bind(this))
    this._layout.livingRoomSelect.add_action(swipeAction)

  _onTemperatureSetpointChange() {
    log('onSwipe')
  }
`

Comment: Sorry, I've never use `ClutterSwipeAction` or other gestures before. It may be you have to add a `Clutter.GestureAction` for `swipe` to be emitted on your action. You might want to search through some gnome-shell code to see how they use gestures and actions there.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find any examples. I think the code is right but the actions are not recognized. Using `GestureAction` and connecting to `gesture-begin` works. Using `TapAction` and `gesture-begin` works, but connecting to `tap` does not. Using `PanAction` (more relaxed than `SwipeAction`) does not work, not `pan` neither `gesture-begin`